# Address location in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

HELP!

I'm trying to put the Address of my product that i have in firebase in a Map but i got the next error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String e.arturo.appmoviles.Model.Product.getAddress()' on a null object reference

My firebase structure

[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCSBg.png)

My button that takes me to the map, where model is my Prodct model

```
btnMapa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Common.currentproduct = model;
            Intent map = new Intent(ProductDetail.this,Maps.class);
            startActivity(map);


        }
    });
```

this is how i initialize `Common.currentproduct = model;`

```
Product model;
```

This is my Model Product

```
public class Product {
private String Name,Address,Image,Description,Price,Link,LatLng;

public Product() {
}

public Product(String name, String address, String image, String description, String price, String link, String latLng) {
    Name = name;
    Address = address;
    Image = image;
    Description = description;
    Price = price;
    Link = link;
    LatLng = latLng;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}

public String getLink() {
    return Link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    Link = link;
}

public String getLatLng() {
    return LatLng;
}

public void setLatLng(String latLng) {
    LatLng = latLng;
}
}
```

I have a class called Common where i put variables, methods, that a used i every part of the program and there i put a a product type object called currentproduct

```
public static Product currentproduct;
```

This is the method that i created to show the product address in the map

```
drawRoute(youLocation,Common.currentproduct.getAddress());
```

This is the method drawRoute

```
private void drawRoute(LatLng youLocation, String address) {
    mService.getGeoCode(address).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

                String lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                        .getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location")
                        .get("lat").toString();

                String lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                        .getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location")
                        .get("lng").toString();

                LatLng productLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.product);
                bitmap=Common.scaleBitmap(bitmap,70,70);

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                        .title(Common.currentproduct.getName())
                        .position(productLocation);
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Show us how how `model` is initialized before `Common.currentproduct = model;`.

Comment: I initialize the model this way `Product model;`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough information. Please edit your question to add more of your code, include full error messages / stack traces including line numbers, and point out exactly where in your code the line numbers point to. For example, very useful would be any other code that mentions `getAddress()` besides inside `onClick()`, even if _you_ think it's an issue with `onClick()`.

Comment: can you upload a json file that the API return?